# Constructing a differential equation with a bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to construct a differential equation $x' = f_a(x)$ where the number of equilibrium solutions depends on $a$ in this fashion: if $a<0$, no equilibrium; if $a=0$, one equilibrium; if $a>0$, four equilibria.

I have started by making $f$ a quartic function where $-a$ is a $y$ intercept (vertical shift).  But this makes the order of equilibria solutions at best $0, 1, 3, 4$ or $0, 2, 4$.  I am stuck on how to make the $a = 0$ equation have only $1$ zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
x' =(x^2-a)(x^2-2a). 
\end{align}

Comment: Oh wow, I did not think of something that simple!  Thank you.